# Theme making direct ajax calls to theme folder

Tags: themes, ajax, 404-error

So, I'm using a wordpress theme (unfortunately, I'm not able to get support for the theme any longer), and it has a contact form that makes a direct ajax call to a php file in the theme's "includes" folder. However, all ajax calls to this file result in a 404 error. As a result, the contact form is not able to successfully post messages.

What server setting is most likely responsible for restricting public access to php files in the themes folder?

Comment: Permissions usually. Have you checked permissions on that directory and file?

Comment: What happens when you access the URL of the file directly from your browser? What do the error logs for your server say? Conventionally speaking, your form should be funneling ajax calls through the `wp_ajax_` hooks. If you're in some type of shared hosting environment, there's a solid chance this file contains a vulnerability that the hosting provider has restricted access to. Most likely the easiest solution would be to replace the form with something new.

Comment: Could you just change the contact form?

Comment: Did you check if the files are present in the location. Moreover there seems to be minor issues in url can you please share screenshot for the same.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson, When the URL is accessed directly, the theme's 404 page is displayed.

Comment: @Pratikbhatt, Yes the files are present at the location. I've tried copying and pasting the file path relative from the public_html folder via ftp (see comment above), and I still get the 404 error.

Comment: I'm thinking the best way to go will be to just use a different form, as suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

server setting that most likely responsible for restricting public access to the php files :

1. Permission (try to set chmod 774 for the php file)
2. .htaccess (try to add rewrite rule for that php file)

maybe i'm wrong but it worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not wrong URL/path issue? Double check it.

Chances are that server settings that are "most likely responsible for restricting public access to php files in the themes folder" are placed in .htaccess file, either in www-root directory or other location (for example, .htaccess file may be in the wp-content directory). There are also chances that the directive is specified in apache's vhost file for specific vhost.

The directive may look like:

```
<Files *.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```

which would produce **403 Forbidden**, not "404 Not found".
So, again, double check URL of that file. 404 Not found is rarely any other thing than exactly what it says - no resource existing for URL.

Apart from all this, you should note that hitting specific .php file in themes directory for any reason is considered to be bad practice - all that you need is already present in Wordpress API. Smart guys that made it has thought of [ajax and made the means of using it right the right way available](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the wrong path since I've copied and pasted the file path from FTP into the browser. When I do that I get the theme's 404 error. 
It could be the vhost file, but I don't think I would have access to that, since this is shared hosting. But, if that would normally result in a 403 error, maybe that's not it.